# PhoneGap Windows app - Image issue

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-build

I would like to generate windows app using PhoneGap and i sorted out all of the things, generated app and requested to publish app in Windows Development website.
I got feedback from Microsoft that my app faied because:

Image file StoreLogo.scale-100.png is a default image.

Image file Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png is a default image.

I was using this guides to create xml:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html#windows
http://www.badpenguin.org/how-to-make-your-ionic-cordova-app-to-run-under-windows-phone-8-1-and-desktop

Here is my config.xml Windows part:

```
<platform name="windows">
    <preference name="windows-identity-name" value="PhonegapBuild.PGBDeveloper" /> 


    <icon src="res/windows/storelogo.png" target="StoreLogo" />
    <icon src="res/windows/smalllogo.png" target="Square30x30Logo" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square44x44Logo.png" target="Square44x44Logo" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square70x70Logo.png" target="Square70x70Logo" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square71x71Logo.png" target="Square71x71Logo" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square150x150Logo.png" target="Square150x150Logo" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square310x310Logo.png" target="Square310x310Logo" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Wide310x150Logo.png" target="Wide310x150Logo" />

    <icon src="res/Windows/logo.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/smalllogo.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/storelogo.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" height="44" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" height="71" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/Windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />

</platform>
```

When i will go to gerated package .appx and open image root folder i can find that some of the icons are PhoneGap default icons:
And it's exactly those two icons. 
I don't have idea how to change config.xml to change those icons. I tried to add

```
<icon src="res/Windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
```

But nothing happened.
All of the needed icons i have i res/Windows directory and pointed in config.xml file but phonegap is not changing those two icons during generation .appx file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience. My message from Windows Dev was:
The branding validation test encountered the following errors:
    Image file StoreLogo.scale-100.png is a default image.
    Image file Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png is a default image.
    Image file Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png is a default image.

I solved these errors as follows:
(1) I deleted all the (Phonegap default) images from the www/src/icon/windows folder.
(2) I created three app icons corresponding to above with the correct sizes i.e. 50x50, 150x150 and 310x150 px. These must be exactly these sizes.
(3) I changes the names of these icons somewhat by leaving out the .scale-100 from each filename.
(4) I mentioned only these new icons in my config.xml as follows:

```
<platform name="winphone">
    <icon src="res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.png" width="310" height="150" />
</platform>
```

(5) Note too that the platform name is "winphone" not "windows" as you have used. I tried "windows" as one of several dozen attempts to solve these problems but it did not work.
(6) There is a simpler and successful solution I tried earlier. This was to use an early version of Phonegap Build by putting the following line in config.xml just before the platform tags viz:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.4.1" />
```

This worked, but I was afraid that such an early Phonegap version might lead to other problems. Mind you, I am using cli-6.0.0 at present but this is to avoid the complexity of Windows 10 Certificate signing.